# Search Keyword Query Language returns less data

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, keywordquery

I have created Managed property called `AssignedTo` for list field "Person or Group" which is having "Allow multiple selections" option set to true. I have performed full crawl. Now when I execute KQL filter with `AssignedTo: User Display Name` I get less number of records then expected. And if I execute with login name without domain it gives proper result. Is it wrong to filter with Display Name?

Comment: Are you using KQL in code or using any search webparts?

Comment: Yes I am using in my custom code. I also tried with search query builder but same result.

Comment: Have you tried to "include duplicates" to your search results, as some results may be treated as duplicates incorrectly?

Comment: Are you talking about keywordQuery.TrimDuplicates = false ?

Comment: Yep. I'm setting this to `false` very often within custom code to get the desired search results.

Comment: Yes that i did too. Problem is there as i get less records while using filter AssignedTo:"displayname" but accurate when using AssignedTo:"loginname"

Comment: If I filter using Display name its correct or not? Then I will dive into more solutions onward.